# Custom placeholders in user story

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to publish user stories on a facebook user's wall using graph api.
My use case is like this:
the user wrote an article that regards a specific community
I created one action 'writes' and two objects 'article' and 'community'.
The two objects have each their pages on my website, where I created all the corresponding meta data for open graph. Tested with the Open Graph Object Debugger and it looks fine.

Now I wanted to customize the way the story is shown.

The default sentence is for example

```
"[user] wrote [article.noun] via [appname]"
```

(brackets are there just to identify placeholders)

but I would like to include information about the community.
So what I did is add a property to the write action, called community that expects a reference to a community object.

Then I changed the sentence to:

```
"[user] wrote [article.noun] on community.title via [appname]"
```

via triboom demo"

but community.title is just treated as plain text and not as a placeholder.
Is there a way to tell FB to use the property value in the sentence?
I could not find any documentation on this.

TIA
s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just found out you need to use {object.property} syntax (doc is here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories#variations) 
Will investigate more and update the answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for posting that! 
How can the placeholders be referenced if there are more than one objects in the sentence? Like, for example, in the "One to Two" sentence:

```
"[user] wrote [article1.noun] and [article2.noun] on community.title via [appname]"
```

Please excuse for posting this as an answer. Unfortunately, I lack the reputation to comment.

Comment: Not sure about that, I noticed that you have some form of autocomplete when your edit your user story in the open graph section of your app settings. When I tried it would use article1 and article2 just like you wrote.